# T-SQL UPDATE with double ROW_NUMBER functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[names1](
    [dept] [varchar](3) PRIMARY KEY,
    [name] [varchar](20)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[names2](
    [dept] [varchar](3) PRIMARY KEY,
    [name] [varchar](20)
)
```

*Insert an equal number rows (more than two) in each of them*, but use different values in the primary key field as much as possible.

**The question is:** Why then when you try to transfer information from the first table to the second in a sequential manner (i.e. by using `ROW_NUMBER()` function) you get an error, or if you dropped the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, wrong values? How can I fix this? I do not want to go through `DELETE` and `INSERT` queries.

The query is as follows:

```
UPDATE
    names2
SET
    dept = n1.dept,
    name = n1.name
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dept) AS RN, * from names2) AS n2,
     (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order BY dept) AS RN, * from names1) AS n1 
WHERE n1.RN  = n2.RN
```

Comment: Please post the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the alias `n2` as the target for your `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE
    n2
SET
    dept = n1.dept,
    name = n1.name
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dept) AS RN, * from names2) AS n2,
     (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order BY dept) AS RN, * from names1) AS n1 
WHERE n1.RN  = n2.RN
```

As it currently stands, I think you end up with `names2` (the target of the `UPDATE`) *not* correlated with `n2` (nor `n1`) and so you've got a hidden cross join occurring in there.